# How to get page link on time of my jekyll site

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

If you goto my jekyll site at the following url

```
http://xxxx.com
```

you will see on the time categories, pages, tages, archive and I would like to find a what to put a link right to my resume page on top too.

I am using github, jekyll and the hoolign theme.  please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll Bootstrap uses `site.pages` and loops through them to create the *Top Nav*.

So to add your **Resume** to that list, you need to do this:

Assuming your Resume is here: `Jekyll Bootstrap Root Directory -> /resume/index.md`.

At the top of `/resume/index.md` add this single line `group: navigation` to your YAML Front Matter after your `title`:

```
---
layout: page
title: Resume
group: navigation
---
```

See this file in JB, which explains:
https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/blob/master/_includes/JB/pages_list

**EDIT**: Oh, I see you are using `/resume.md` and `/resume/index.md` for the same content. So add the `group: navigation` line to the one which you want in the main nav, but not both.

Comment: that's great but how can I get it at the end of the list

Comment: @SJS it should show up at the end of the list automatically. It does for me when I test it with your same setup. If you have more than ONE page you want to add (beyond the default list), there is no way to order them at this time. But with just your ONE Resume page added it will show up at the end. See here about ordering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266369/how-to-change-the-default-order-pages-in-jekyll