# GitHub Pages how to create a TOC?

Tags: github, documentation, github-pages, tableofcontents

I have a project on github and I want to generate GitHub Pages for it. But not just one page, I want to create a structure like this: [Welcome to phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation.

I've been reading documentation, articles, forums, stackoverflow etc and I still don't get how make this work.

My project has a **master** and **gh-pages** branches:

The content of the **master** is:
docs (folder) (contains six md files)
images (folder)
README.md (Just two sentences)

When I've created the **gh-pages** it copied **all content from the master**, so the two branches are even.

The content of the **master**/README.md  is different from the **gh-pages**/README.md

My [site/Web Pages](https://andreamussap.github.io/article-Get-Healthy-at-Work/) shows the content of the master/README.md like a heading, and the content of gh-pages/README.md like the body of the page.

Can someone help me on how to show the files of my project? not just the README file??
Thanks, Andrea.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking. Can you please provide a link to your repository? Do you maybe have some mockups showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi @KevinWorkman
sorry if my question is not clear to you. I wanted to use mkdocs with github pages to create a site for my documentation.

After an extensivily research I got it. 

[Here](https://andreamussap.github.io/article-Get-Healthy-at-Work/) is the result that I wanted.

Thank you for your attention. I'll look at how to close this question.
Andrea.

Comment: a list of all pages can be created with the use of `site.pages` see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983971/574981) for more information