# Generate github pages with navigation elements

Tags: github, jekyll

I have a project on github that includes a number of markdown files (introduction, user guide, examples, reference).

I want to create a website using Github Pages based on these files that also includes a navigation element of some sorts, like a simple sidebar containing links to all the generated pages.

It seems that, out-of-the-box, pages generated with Github Pages are all stand-alone with no way to navigate between them.

Is there an easy way to achieve this, or is this use case too complicated for github pages? The documentation seems to be lacking on this point.

Answer (score -1):

The Markdown to link to pages within the same folder

```
[__PageA__](PageA.md)
[__PageB__](PageB.md)
```

To link to pages in other folders just put in the relative link like this

```
[__PageC__](FolderC/PageC.md)
[__PageX__](../../PageX.md)
```

This works for files hosted on GitHub ... how you then use these to generate a standalone website you would need a tool that converts Markdown to HTML, something I have not looked into.

Comment: This is helpful as far as it goes, but  the original post was asking about the possibility of adding navigation elements, like a sidebar - I'm inferring that they're looking for something that would add new links to all existing pages automatically (or semi-automatically). Which is what I came here looking for too! Adding links from every page to every page gets awkward pretty quick. I'd settle for links on every page in a single editable bar of some sort...

Comment: i think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983971/574981) can help here too?